# How to compare two dataframes cell by cell?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes containing the result of a corr() from different parts of a single source (csv). Now I want to compare all the values in the two dataframes to check if they are equal or even if they fall within a particular range. So the puseudo code would be something like:

```
df1['column1']['row1'] == df2['column1']['row1']
```

Is there a simple way of doing this in Pandas?

Comment: can't you do `df1 == df2`?

Comment: @EdChum But that won't give me the cell for which the values are equal (or unequal), will it? It will return `False` even if only cell in the dataframes is different.

Comment: It will if the index, column values and shape of the dfs match

Comment: Right, Ed's answer won't give you the cells, it gives you an **entire** dataframe of booleans which you can use as a mask to look at True values, or False values, or whatever you want.  Look in the docs at boolean selection and masking.

Comment: If you're after the values that agree than `df1[df1==df2]` will show those values, the inverse will return where the values disagree `df1[df1 != df2]` and `df2[df1 != df2]`

Comment: @JohnE - Ok, i will try it out and also read the topics you mentioned, I am new to Python and Pandas, so have to do a lot of catching up :)

Comment: Also, will the same logic hold for the other part of my question? i.e. `df2 - df1 / df1 + df2 /2 *100 < 10` ... bascially I want to check if the percetage difference between corresponding two cells is less than 10%.

Comment: So long as the index, columns and shape agree then yes that should work

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways to do that. One of the ways I follow is as below:

```
df3 = df2[df1.ne(df2).any(axis=1)]
```

df3 will list out all the rows in which atleast one cell will not match.
FYI, `ne` here stands for `not equal`.

Example:

create df1

```
data = [['batman', 10], ['joker', 15], ['alfred', 14]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
```

create df2 which is slightly different from df1

```
data = [['batman', 10], ['joker', 6], ['alfred', 17]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
```

extract the rows with atleast one unequal cell

```
df3 = df2[df1.ne(df2).any(axis=1)]
df3
```

print the the resultant df3

```
   Name  Age
1  joker    6      // the age is different in df1 and df2 for joker
2  alfred   17      // the age is different in df1 and df2 for alfred
```

Now, from the resultant dataframe, you can check the range requirements as per your business case.